# Sharing refs between react-imask, react-bootstrap, and react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-hook-form, imaskjs, react-imask

I'm currently using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) and [react-imask](https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/tree/master/packages/react-imask) together using [their example](https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/tree/master/packages/react-imask#extend-existing-components) with IMaskMixin:

```
import { IMaskMixin } from 'react-imask';
import { FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';

const MaskedFormControl = IMaskMixin(({inputRef, ...props}) => (
  <FormControl
    {...props}
    ref={inputRef} 
  />
));
```

Now, I would like to use [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) with this control;

```
const { register } = useForm();
<MaskedFormControl {...register('name')} />
```

The spread on the register function is the equivalent of this

```
const { onChange, onBlur, name, ref } = register('name');
```

So it is expecting the ref to access the input ref, the values in react-hook-form never get set with what is typed in the input.

I use MasedFormControl in places I dont' use react-hook-form so I would like to make it work with or without react-hook-form.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Not in particular for Bootstrap, but I'll show general idea on how to integrate react-imask, react-hook-form with any kind of input:

1. Define schema

```
  const schema = yup.object({
    phone: yup
      .string()
      .required('Phone is required')
      .length(10, 'Phone must contain 10 digits'),
  });
```

2. Declare form

```
  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    mode: 'onTouched',
    defaultValues: {
      phone: "4437787349",
    },
  });
```

3. Add imask

```
  const mask = useIMask({
    mask: '(000) 000-00-00',
  });
```

4. Render input component

```
  <Controller
    render={(params) => (
      <input
        name={params.field.name}
        onBlur={params.field.onBlur}
        defaultValue={params.field.value}
        ref={mask.ref}
        onChange={() =>
          params.field.onChange({
            target: { value: mask.unmaskedValue },
          })
        }
        placeholder="Phone number"
      />
      // show error messages
      // <p>{params.fieldState.error?.message}</p>
    )}
    name="phone"
    control={control}
  />
```

Comment: thank you I'll give this a try and report back